# QGIS 3.28 error writing to file C:\apps\qgis-ltr\symsrv.dll Verify that you have access to that directory

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I encounter this error when trying to install QGIS 3.28.13 Firenze on Windows:

[image]

What can cause this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you allowed to install software on your PC? Do you have admin rights?